# Integer to its prime factors

Tags: integer, prime-factoring

hey i need to desing a program that inputs an integer and outputs the prime factors of the integer example 
660 input n output is 2 2 3 5 11

Comment: You should first post what have you tried - ideas, code snippets, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Break the problem down. Firstly, you need a list of every prime number smaller than the square root of the input. You can obtain this list slowly through trial division, or quickly by using something like [Eratosthenes' Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) - implement that, and you're halfway there. Everything else should fall into place.